# How to wrap PL/SQL source code in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can I use user defined wrap function or unwrapped method in Oracle? Because default wrapping code is can be unwrapped.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Oracle needs to be able to read the wrapped source code to be able to use it so has to be able to unwrap it internally. If Oracle can unwrap it then so can other applications - at best this is an additional layer of security-through-obscurity - it is not encryption of the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the wrapped procedure the same way that you use an unwrapped procedure.  Call it from SQL or PL/SQL.  Wrapping has no effect on calling the run-time behaviour of the stored procedure.  The procedure is still in `ALL_OBJECTS` and its parameters are still in `ALL_ARGUMENTS`.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's documentation [says](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/wrap.htm#LNPLS016):

> Wrapping a PL/SQL unit prevents most users from examining the source
> code, but might not stop all of them.

If you read Pete Finnigan's [analyis](https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-06/BH-US-06-Finnigan.pdf) of the wrapping mechanism, the wrapped code is just an encoding of the DIANA or Interface Description Languange (IDL) version of your source code. I don't see any way how you can change the wrapping mechanism and still be valid IDL.

After unwrapping, I normally give up if the PL/SQL package calls C functions. So you might try writing C libraries. They seem to be much harder to re-engineer...